# What sort of data format to use for a project dealing with massive quantities of personalized data?

Tags: java, database

I'm working on an application for a Nursing students; It is a program where a user enters data about their Patient's Vitals, Skin Assessments, Medicine Administered, etc.

**Flowchart for program structure in respect to Data:**

[image: http://puu.sh/1fIWi]

That data needs to be saved in a structure divisible by Patient and then by the Time recorded. Problem is this is going to be a HUGE amount of data since entries need to be made every 15 minutes.

**Flowchart for what interactions necessary between the project and its data:**

[image: http://puu.sh/1gqGN]

*request patient var over Time* and *request populate timeline* both search for all entries of that patient between two given dates.

The best way I can think of how to organize this data is directory based:

**data/PatientName/Month/19102012.file** (the date 19 Oct 2012, for quick omission of ignored dates)
This way might be okay but it feels really hacked together, what better organization should I use for this data?

Comment: Why don't you use a Database?

Comment: Sidenote: if you ever want to be able to find your files again, store them like **20121019.file** (example for 19. Oct. 2012) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I honestly don't think students entering patient data every 15 minutes qualifies as *HUGE* these days. As such, virtually any technology would be of use. Some sort of relational database is an obvious choice, and given the above, I don't think you need anything remotely enterprise-scale.

One question that springs to mind is, is security important ? This is medical data, after all. That may influence the technology you choose since filesystems implement security in a radically different fashion to (say) the filesystem.

The one piece of advice I can give now is to abstract your data storage away from the rest of your solution. That way you can implement something trivial now and replace it easily in the future as your requirements solidify.

Comment: I don't believe the security is of major importance in this case, considering this is for students with simulation patients. Though I might as well make it as secure as I can?

Comment: Well, perhaps enough to prevent users fiddling figures or accidently modifying figures they shouldn't. But it sounds like it you don't need the sort of security a real medical app would

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `custom class`(**A POJO**) containing all the parameters needed as properties in that `POJO`, and stuff the instances created of that `POJO` in some database.

Using `Database` might be an elegant way to handle huge amount of data.

Comment: when you say "database", I assume you're referring to "relational database"? what makes you say that it's ideal in this case? (I happen to agree with you, on instinct, but it's hard to say why)

Comment: @mfrankli What makes you thing that a relation database would be appropriate in this scenario? ;-)

Comment: @mfrankli, Well, not necessarly a Relational database, but a different one can be used like `MongoDB`.

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested directory-based approach would realistically probably be fine. As Brian and Rohit pointed out, the key is that you want to abstract out the data storage. In other words, you should have some interfaces between components of your system that provide the data access methods that you *want*, and then link up what you *want* (i.e., request a specific patient, over some time period, etc) with what you *have* (i.e., a filesystem, or a database, etc).

As Brian pointed out, in today's world "huge" refers to an entirely different scale than recording entries every 15 minutes. I would build something that *works*, and then address the scale problem when and if it arises. There are lots of other important things to worry about as well, such as security, reliability, etc.